# How to add more than one color pin to a mapview.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a map that has 3 categories of points of interest. At the moment I have got them to display however they are all the same color. How can I get them to display a color depending to what category they are in?

I have had a search around and couldn't find anything that I could understand to apply to my code.

Here is my current code for annotating the pins:

```
-(void)pins:(NSString *)name lat:(NSString *)lat lon:(NSString *)lon poiID:(NSString *)poiID
{

    //cast string to float
    CGFloat Lat = (CGFloat)[lat floatValue];
    CGFloat Lon = (CGFloat)[lon floatValue];

    //Set coordinates of pin
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    coordinate.latitude = Lat;
    coordinate.longitude = Lon;

    //Create Pin
    MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    //set details
    [annotation setCoordinate:coordinate];
    [annotation setTitle:name];
    [annotation setAccessibilityLabel:poiID]; //set the label eq to the id so we know which poi page to go to


    // Add pin to map
    [self.showMapView addAnnotation:annotation];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    //create annotation
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"pinView"];
    if (!pinView) {
        pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pinView"];
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        pinView.animatesDrop = FALSE;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;

        //details button
        UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

    } else {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return pinView;
}
```

Here is the rest of my [Code](http://pastebin.com/sxAmutVr) incase it is needed.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple enough to do, just add an if statement to check the title or subtitle. When I was using maps, my annotation class had a subtitle where it would say what the place was, i.e. hotel, airport etc. I would just add an if statement to check, and then set what the pin point was and set up what colour I wanted the pin to be

```
if([annotation.subtitle isEqualToString:@"Hotel"])
    {
        pinView.animatesDrop=YES;
        pinView.pinColor=MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;


    }else if([annotation.subtitle isEqualToString:@"Airport"])
    {
      pinView.animatesDrop=YES;
        pinView.pinColor=MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    }
```

or if you want it to be an image, just use

```
pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"airportMarker.png"];
```

EDIT: UPDATED CODE

Create a custom annotation class like this

```
@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation> 
{

    CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinate;
    NSString*               title;
    NSString*               subtitle;
    NSInteger categoryID;
}
@property NSInteger categoryID;
@property (nonatomic, assign)   CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy)     NSString*               title;
@property (nonatomic, copy)     NSString*               subtitle;

@end
```

Then when you are adding the objects to screen, give each one an ID, i.e

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D hotelCoordinates1;
hotelCoordinates1.latitude = 35.38355;
hotelCoordinates1.longitude = 1.11004;
MyAnnotation* exampleHotel=[[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
exampleHotel.coordinate=hotelCoordinates1;
exampleHotel.title=@"Example Hotel";
exampleHotel.subtitle=@"Hotel";
exampleHotel.categoryID = 1;
```

Then inside this method

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    //create annotation
```

just do this

```
if([(MyAnnotation*)annotation categoryID] == 1)
        {

        }
```

You need to ensure you cast the annotation to whatever the name of the class you created. And thats it. Hope that helps!!

Comment: I dont think that define color by name of Annotation is goo solution, because this is not unique.

Comment: He wants to assign colours based on categories, this code is perfect for that. He has 3 categories, so if can set up different colours for each category using the code I gave. And in my example, it wasn't the name of the annotation, it was the subtitle, which in my case was how I categorised annotations.

Comment: The problem is that I wont know any of the names or have a subtitle. All my content will be dynamic. So if another category is added through my web service this wouldnt work :/

Comment: Ah in your question you said you had 3 categories, so I assumed the content being added would fit into those 3 categories. Even if the content is dynamic, you should have some way of identifying what is being added, either by giving it a subtitle or giving it a unique ID that can be used to decide what colour it should be. Otherwise how else could you possibly separate the content into different colours.

Comment: How can you give it an ID? That would work because I have a catID

Comment: I amended by answer with code showing you how to do it. Hope it helps!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18796/discussion-between-will-and-adamm)

Answer (score 2):

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
   static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[MymapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID] autorelease];
    }

    if (annotation == MymapView.userLocation)
        return nil;
    /////i give just an example with category 
    if(category == 1){
       annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Category1.png"];
    }
    else if(category == 2){
       annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Category2.png"];
    }

    annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView.tag = 101;

    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: How does it know which pins are in which cat though?

Comment: in your -(void)pins:(NSString *)name lat:(NSString *)lat lon:(NSString *)lon poiID:(NSString *)poiID this method paste above code and after use name with category and assign name.png for pinView...

Answer (score 1):

You have to override mkAnnotation class and define specyfic field where you declare categories id. When you create Annotation on map set the id, and on the delegate viewForAnnotation check the id annotation, and check which color you have to use for pin for current id.

You can also see this post to see how to ovveride MKAnnotation class: [MKAnnotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058659/mapview-with-multiple-annotations-with-callouts-how-to-pass-title-to-next-view/13058850#13058850)